# set initial values for class

Tags: javascript, parse-server

here is my class

```
export default class Store extends Parse.Object {
    constructor() {
        super('Store');

        this.product = [];
    }
}
```

and after importing it I do this

```
let store = new Store();
```

but the issue is the value of product is not initialized, it is still undefined.

any ideas how to solve this issue?
I dont want to initialize after I create the instance, like this

```
store.set('product', []);
```

Comment: Have you made sure that the constructor is called?

Comment: how do you import it ?

Comment: @PeterMader constructor is being called, sure

Comment: @oliv37 import Store from '../model';

Comment: and `store.product` returns `undefined` ?

Comment: store.get('product') //undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution, here is how it will work

```
export default class Store extends Parse.Object {
    constructor() {
        super('Store');

        this.set('product', []);
    }
}
```

but the docs shows as bellow, which is not working !

```
class Monster extends Parse.Object {
  constructor() {
    // Pass the ClassName to the Parse.Object constructor
    super('Monster');
    // All other initialization
    this.sound = 'Rawr';
  }

}
```

Comment: I had problems with this following the guide ages ago and gave up on adding constructors. So the solution is just to use `this.set(property,value)` instead of `this.property(value)` ?